# How to get JSON array from file with getJSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

How could I get an array json of a json file with javascript and jquery

I was triyng with the next code, with it doesnt work:

```
var questions = [];
function getArray(){
    $.getJSON('questions.json', function (json) {
        for (var key in json) {
            if (json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                var item = json[key];
                questions.push({
                    Category: item.Category
                });
            }
        }
        return questions;
    })
}
```

this is the json file called: questions.json

```
{
"Biology":{
    "Category":{
        "cell":{
            "question1":{
                "que1":"What is the cell?"
            },
            "option1":{
                "op1":"The cell is the basic structural and functional unit",
                "op2":"is a fictional supervillain in Dragon Ball"
            },
            "answer1":"opt1"
        }
    }
},
"Astronomy":{
    "Category":{
        "Mars":{
            "question1":{
                "que1":"How many moons does Mars?"
            },
            "option1":{
                "op1":"5",
                "op2":"2"
            },
            "answer1":"opt2"
        }
    }
}
}
```

I want to get an array with this format {Biology:{Category:{cell:{question1....}}}}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`$.getJSON` is an asynchronous function, so returning something inside that function does nothing, as it's not in scope, or received yet. You should probably do something like:

```
function getArray(){
    return $.getJSON('questions.json');
}

getArray().done(function(json) {
    // now you can use json
    var questions = [];
    $.each(json, function(key, val) {
        questions[key] = { Category: val.Category };
    });
});
```

Comment: By the way how could i get the value for example of Astronomy??
console.log(questions[1].[Astronomy]), on this way is ok?

Comment: try it console.log(questions[1][Category])

Comment: Did you try `questions.Astronomy`? Using the key that way actually makes into an object, so push() would be the way to go if you wanted a number indexed array.

Answer (score 3):

Your conditional within the `for` loop prevents anything from being added to your array. Instead, check if your json object has the property, then get the value and add it to your array. In other words:

`if (questions.hasOwnProperty(key))` should be `if (json.hasOwnProperty(key))`

Also, you can't simply `return` the result of an AJAX call like that, because the method runs asynchronously. That `return` is actually applied to the inner `success` function callback, not `getArray`. You have to use a callback pattern in order to pass the data only once it has been received, and operate on it accordingly.

(Of course since the array is defined in the outer scope you wouldn't have to return it anyway, but if you attempted to use it before the AJAX method ended it would be empty.)

Assuming you are going to render it to the DOM using a method called `renderJSON`:

```
var questions = [];
function getArray(){
    $.getJSON('questions.json', function (json) {
        for (var key in json) {
            if (json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                var item = json[key];
                questions.push({
                    Category: item.Category
                });
            }
        }
        renderJSON(questions);
    });
}
```

Comment: @chikatetsu Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/H2jQD/. What do you mean by 'not working'? What do you expect it to do?

Comment: P.S. @whoeverdownvoted It's always good to explain why...OP changed code after my post, hence your not being able to see the old problem.