# why my array json is empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have next code which load an file json, and make an array called questions.
if i do an console.log(JSON.stringify(questions)) inside getArray function it works ok, but if I do the same outsite the function it doesn't work, I tried with 
alert(JSON.stringify(questions)) and alert(questions.length) it return [] and 0, where's my mistake??

```
var questions = [];
function getArray(){
    $.getJSON('questions.json', function (json) {
        for (var key in json) {
            if (json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                var item = json[key]; 
                questions.push({
                    Category: item.Category
                });
            }
        }
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(questions)); //it works
           return questions;
    });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
getArray();
});

alert(JSON.stringify(questions)) //return []
alert(questions.length) //return 0
```

Comment: The issue is timing, as discussed in the [previous answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14916940/how-to-get-array-json-of-json-file). The `alert()`s are synchronous and execute before anything else because the rest is asynchronous and event-driven. Just because code is written in a particular order doesn't guarantee it executes in that same order, especially when working with events.

Comment: this gets asked 5 times a day... AJAX is asynchronous

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `return` because it's asynchoronous:

```
var callback = function(questions) {
    // Do something with questions here.
    alert(questions.length);
}

var questions = [];
function getArray(){
    $.getJSON('questions.json', function (json) {
        for (var key in json) {
            if (json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                var item = json[key]; 
                questions.push({
                    Category: item.Category
                });
            }
        }
        callback(questions);
    });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
getArray();
});
```